# Python Multiprocessing to publish to multiple topics

Tags: python, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently have a setup where I have about 10 shell scripts that listen to 10 different KNX addresses (using the shell command grouplisten) and publish their state to a ROS topic. These scripts can run in the background, so it's quite convenient to 'listen' to the state of these devices.

I tried to replace these 10 scripts with a single python program that basically does this:

1. Declare a subprocess.Popen for each device, to listen to its knx device.

> ```
> self.listen_stat = subprocess.Popen(self.cmds,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,preexec_fn=os.setsid)
> ```

2. Declare the node (in `__main__`) , and topic for each device ( in `device.__init__()`).

> ```
> class DeviceProp:
> ```

```
    def __init__(self):
      ...
      self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.name,Int32,latch=True)
```

3. Call a `talker` function like so:

> 

```
try:
  for device in device_props:
       p = multiprocessing.Process(target=device.device_talker)
       procs.append(p)
       p.start()
except (KeyboardInterrupt,rospy.ROSInterruptException,IOError) as e:
    for p in procs:
       p.join()
```

(The device_talker basically just publishes new data to `device.pub`)

What happens is that the logs suggest data is being published, but I don't see anything on when I subscribe to those topics or if I do `rostopic echo`. If I run `rostopic pub` from a new shell, I get the data on the topic as expected. I've also added a rospy.sleep(1) at multiple places (in loops too) so that even if I lose the first few messages, I *should* get the later ones. But I don't.

Any suggestions on what I should do?
(In case you are wondering why - I want to replace 10 scripts with 1 for easier code management. Also, Since I can store all address and device props in a yaml file, it will be trivial to add, or edit the configuration file).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119511/python-multiprocessing-to-publish-to-multiple-topics/) by [Mandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/11001/mandar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2014-01-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/11001/mandar/) on 2014-01-20**:
I realize that I may be using the multiprocessing module wrong to share variables (the publisher for instance). It would be helpful if someone could suggest a way to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to solve this problem (Note to self: Read the python docs). Turns out that a new process thread creates a copy of all the data from the parent, and I had not taken care of this properly.

The way I solved it was thus: I called the `Popen` (listen_stat in this case) from the device method get_status:

```
 def get_status(self):
    varnum = 0  # for testing only
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
       self.response_line = self.listen_stat.stdout.readline().split()
       self.new_detect.value = int(self.response_line[varnum])
```

The important detail was declaring the variable `new_detect` as a [multiprocessing.Value()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) and then calling this function instead for the multiprocess.

```
stat_procs = []
for device in device_props:
    sp = multiprocessing.Process(target=device.get_status)
    stat_procs.append(sp)
    sp.start()
```

The actual publisher then was just called in a normal loop:

```
try:
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        for device in device_props:
            device.device_talker()
except (KeyboardInterrupt,rospy.ROSInterruptException,IOError) as e:
    for p in stat_procs:
       p.join()
```

Hope this helps the others.

---

Originally posted by [Mandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/11001/mandar/) with karma: 73 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on 2017-06-22**:
Hi,
I am trying to do the same thing. However, I want to create multiple publishers in a single ros node. But when I call the publish method inside a while loop, only the first called publisher is invoked.

Could you please suggest suitable multi threading for this purpose ?